# change form_for model, and url params with a helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dynamic, helper, form-for

What would be the best way to make a form_for dynamic? Using a helper?
I need to be able to set in view a different controller and action for this form_for

I need to change between:

```
= simple_form_for @profile, :url => url_for(:controller => 'welcome', :action => 'update'), :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
```

and

```
= simple_form_for @profile, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
```

in an easy way.
What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: If too dry it will burn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= simple_form_for @profile, :url => criteria ? url_for(:controller => 'welcome', :action => 'update') : nil, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
```

if the criteria is true, `welcome#update` is used, else `@profile`

Comment: ah that is really simple thanks for pointing out! I accept answer as soon as possible